# Service Worker clients.openWindow opens start_url from manifest instead of the requested URL

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, web-push

I have a service worker that receives push notifications and it works well in Chrome for desktop, but not in Chrome for Android.

Some times it works as expected, but sometimes it starts opening the start_url value of the manifest.json instead of the value of the notificationURL variable.

The notification URL looks like:
https://www.example.com/abc/123/?source=notification

The manifest start_url value looks like:
https://www.example.com/?source=manifest

Sample code:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {

    var notificationURL = event.notification.data.url;

    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window'
    }).then(function(clientList) {

        for ( var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++ ) {
            var client = clientList[i];
            if ( client.url === notificationURL && 'focus' in client ) {
                return client.focus();
            }
        }

        if ( 'openWindow' in clients ) {

            // This prints "notificationURL: https://www.example.com/abc/123/?source=notification".
            console.log('notificationURL:', notificationURL);

            // But this opens "https://www.example.com/?source=manifest".
            return clients.openWindow(notificationURL);
        }

    }));

});
```

So, for some reason in some cases if the notification URL starts with "https://www.example.com" the code above will always open https://www.example.com/?source=manifest.

This is related with the fact that I've added the site to my home screen?

This is a expected behavior?

**Note:** It opens the manifest start_url, but not in standalone mode.

Answer (score 2):

Just before `return client.focus();`

add this line

`client.navigate(notificationURL);`

Also,
Change `return clients.openWindow(notificationURL)`

to

`return clients.openWindow(notificationURL).then(function(client){
       client.navigate(notificationURL);
});`

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem (or actually it seems to be exactly the opposite): the clients.openwindow from my push notifications worked just fine when I had just the browser to deal with. So http://example.com/some/path/page was opened without any problems.

However, as soon as someone installed the standalone app using 'add to homescreen' it wouldn't work anymore. The app would simply always open the start_url no matter which URL I supplied. I tried everything; changing the scope in my manifest and the serviceworker, desperate attempts to call navigate() on the window after the openWindow promise was fulfilled (the .then() didn't even get called wtf), etc. I think I've read the entire internet on the subject by now but I didn't find a solution...

At the end, I decided to change 'display: "standalone"' to 'display: "browser"' in my manifest. And the links worked again! Of course, this changes the behaviour of your app to not being very appy anymore (it becomes more like a shortcut to a webpage), but for me it was an acceptable workaround that solved the problem.

I got the feeling that opening a page within your installed standalone app is not supported at the moment. If anyone has an idea that suggests otherwise I'm all ears ;-)

Comment: I found another workaround. If the URL that I'm trying to open has the same schema and host of the start_url, it opens the start_url. But if I change the schema (https) to http, it opens the correct URL and my server makes a redirect to https. But this comes with some security issues...